# PHP REST Api works on localserver but not on Web Hosting?

Tags: php, rest, api, hosting, slim

I have just created a simple REST Api following this [small video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhcQXFeor9g) using Slim Framework 3.x. I was just getting started and I followed the instructions in the video and created a simple route like this

```
$app->get('/', function($request, $response)
  {
    return 'Home';
  });
```

This works on localserver (XAMP) when I open the link `

> localserver/project_name/public/

` I get "Home" returned on the page. 
After that I simply Zipped the project folder and uploaded it to my Web Hosting, htdocs folder. I extracted the zipped project, which included the "composer.phar" and "vendor" folder. I try the same thing again, i.e., I run the url

> www.mysite.com/project_name/public/

All I've done is change `"localserver"` with `www.mysite.com` but the browser tells me that my domain

> is currently unable to handle this request.

I know this might be something very obvious but I am a novice in php and REST Api's. So any help is appreciated. Also some things I think might matter are, The web hosting that I am using is Plesk based. I have a mysql database Running on the hosting and simple php files run when run individually. For example if I run simple call a test.php file with some database query in it and some echo, it will run successfully. Even if you can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it. Oh, and I don't have access to php.ini on the hosting. I was only provided with one login that lets me login to the hosting and I can see `htdocs` folder among some others. I have attached an 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5vo8.png) of the view I get after logging in, to give you more perspective of the type of hosting I have. I am hosting a website in the httpdocs directory as well. ASP.NET developed

I just need some direction as to what I need to do to be able to publish my REST api to my hosting and be able to access it through this android app that I am building. What do i need to do on my server? What settings to change to make the api work?

Comment: Does the working `test.php` live in the htdocs directory?

Comment: test.php lives in the directory `httpdocs/my_folder/` directory